# Find multiple elements of specific type

Tags: html-table, cypress

Given something like this:

```html
<table>
 <tr id="row">
  <td>......</td>
  <td>......</td>
  <td>......</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="row">
  ...
```

The tds have no id or other identificator.

How can I find, for instance, the third ?

I can find any `<td>` tag like this:

```js
cy.get("td")
```

And I seem to be able to get a specific row like this:

```js
cy.get("#row")[0]
```

But this does not work:

```js
cy.get("#row")[0].cy.get("td")
```

What I want to do, is to be able to get the contents of, for instance, the third `<td>` in every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use `cy.eq()` to get an item from an array at a specific index.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq)

> Get A DOM element at a specific index in an array of elements.

So, given the example you provided:

```js
cy.get('td')
  .eq(2)
  ...
// eq is index-0
```

Additionally, Cypress provides [`.first()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/first) and [`.last`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/last) as convenience functions to get the first and last item in the array, respectively. (No convenience functions for third though)

If you need to find a specific *row* by an index, and then the specific `td` underneath it, the proper way would be to use [`.find()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find) or another Cypress function to query only off of the yielded `row`.

```js
cy.get('#row')
  .eq(0) // or .first()
  .find('td')
  .eq(2)
  ...
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 5):

Check out [cy.table()](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cy-table/), it makes handling rows and columns much easier.

**Install**

```js
yarn add -D cypress-map
//or
npm i -D cypress-map
```

```js
import 'cypress-map'

cy.get('table tbody')
  .table(2, 0, 1)                                      // 2nd column only
  .should('deep.eq', [['Text'], ['Not text']])
```

or flat version

```js
cy.get('table tbody')
  .table(2, 0, 1)
  .invoke('flatMap', Cypress._.identity)
  .should('deep.eq', ['Text', 'Not text'])
```

[image]